# Mapinfo with Postgis - not installed in schema public

Tags: postgis, mapinfo

I'm aware of this

https://postgis.net/2017/11/07/tip-move-postgis-schema/

and I followed the steps and now I can see the tables in QGis; the problem now is MapInfo: I can open the table but I can't make it mappable with PostGIS (the 'postgis' option does not appear in the make table mappable option); is there some documentation about this?

Edit: There is a mapinfo.mapcatalog table in the database, the problem started when I changed the schema for postgis (from schema 'public' to another schema)

Comment: So you can't select the PostGIS schema in the Schema dropdown in the dialog where you select tables to make mappable in MapInfo Pro?

Comment: yes, I can't; I'm sure is not a grants issue

Comment: Can you share a scrren dump of the dialog just to make sure we are talking about the same thing?